# Make second flex column scrollable

Tags: html, css

I saw this example from [Flex: Scrollable div inside flex-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157058/flex-scrollable-div-inside-flex-column) and attempted to use it, but I couldn't get it to work. Something is wrong, could someone look at my code and tell me where I went wrong with my code?

A row that contains two columns; left is 75% width and right is 25% width. Right column height must be the same as the left column, therefore; when the right column has overflowing content, then right column should be scrollable.

Live: http://gnt.staatus.eu/

Here's HTML code:

```
<div id="row">
    <div id="content">
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"  controls preload="auto" data-setup='{ "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto", "fluid": true }'>
            <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="hidden" />
            <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
        </video>
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
        <div id="chat2">
            <ul>
                <li>username: Tanaka THAI KICKU</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

and here's stylesheet:

```
#content {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content a {
    color: white;
}

#chat {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;

    color: white;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 0px;
}

#chat2 {
    overflow: auto;
}

#chat2 ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}

#row {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not achievable 100% using `flex`. You have to go for some custom CSS as well. Flexbox always fits the height to the maximum height of the contents. In your case you need to remove the second element from flex view and need to place it with positioning.

In the below example the parent element has `display: flex` and `position: relative`. The second child element is set to `position: absolute` 75% left and  `overflow: auto`. This makes the parent take the height of first child and make the second child scrollable.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.child-1, .child-2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
.child-1  {
    flex: 0 1 75%;
}
.child-2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">
        <p>Reference Div</p>
        <p>Reference Div</p>
        <p>Reference Div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
        <p>Scrolling Div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution to your problem:**

```css
#content {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    /* flex-basis: 75%; */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content a {
    color: white;
}

#chat {
    /* flex: 1; */
    /* flex-basis: 25%; */
    /* display: flex; */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* flex-direction: column; */

    color: white;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 0px;
    /* Added */
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#chat2 {
    overflow: auto;
}

#chat2 ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}

#row {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*Added*/
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gnt.staatus.eu/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video-js.css">

<div id="row">
    <div id="content">
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"  controls preload="auto" data-setup='{ "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto", "fluid": true }'>
            <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://gnt.staatus.eu/hls/test.m3u8" />
            <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
        </video>
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
        <div id="chat2">
            <ul>
                <li>username: Tanaka THAI KICKU</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
                <li>username: text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works! Happy new year! Also other recommended grid instead of flex, maybe I should look into that, when it was not achievable 100% using flex.

Comment: @Typhome welcome. Please approve the answer if this is what you are looking for. Happy to have an upvote aswell .

Comment: Hello Nitheesh, I need help again. I forgot about text input field, I wanted to make this stick to top (in right column), not being in scrollable div. I have been trying to mess with code, still unsuccessful. https://jsfiddle.net/3sv5cx8r/

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep the heights the same you should consider Grid instead of flex-box

**Grid is Container-Based, Flexbox is Content-Based**

In flexbox layout, the size of a cell (flex-item) is defined inside the flex-item itself, and in the grid layout, the size of a cell (grid-item) is defined inside the grid-container.

[image]

Here is a link that describes the differences with examples 
[Grid VS Flex](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2018/09/grid-vs-flexbox-which-should-you-choose/)

```css
/* Flexbox row styles */
.row-flex {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row-flex div {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
}
/* Grid row styles */
.row-grid {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
.row-grid div {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Flexbox</h2>
<div class="row-flex">
    <div>1 2 3  4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
 
<h2>Grid</h2>
<div class="row-grid">
    <div>1 2 3  4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I will look into that grid. Happy new year!

Comment: Thanks and to you too .

Answer (score 1):

You should add to `#row` `max-height` then the `overflow` will work.

```css
#content {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content a {
  color: white;
}

#chat {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0px;
}

#chat2 {
  overflow: auto;
}

#chat2 ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="row">
  <div id="content">
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" data-setup='{ "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto", "fluid": true }'>
            <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://gnt.staatus.eu/hls/test.m3u8" />
            <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
        </video>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.5/video.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div id="chat">
    <div id="chat2">
      <ul>
        <li>username: Tanaka THAI KICKU</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
        <li>username: text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```