# Vaadin: How to implement horizontal layout with scrollable column?

Tags: java, layout, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to implement a HorizontalLayout with the table content area on the left side and the accordion-based details column on the right. The content area should occupy the remaining page height (basically, `100vh - navbarHeight`) and it should not exceed that value.

The issue is in the details column, specifically with the accordion. Expanded panels can contain many rows, so I put the accordion inside a scroller, but it's not working. Instead of getting a scrollable accordion, it expands the root container and I get scrollable window instead.

[image]

Simplified code:

```java
var grid = new Grid<>(Pojo.class, false);

var tableBox = new VerticalLayout(grid);
tableBox.setHeightFull();

var accordion = new Accordion();
accordion.setWidthFull();

var detailsBox = new Scroller(accordion);
detailsBox.setScrollDirection(Scroller.ScrollDirection.VERTICAL);
detailsBox.setWidth("450px");

var layout = new HorizontalLayout();
layout.add(tableBox);
layout.add(detailsBox);
layout.setFlexGrow(1, tableBox);
layout.setFlexGrow(0, detailsBox);
layout.setSizeFull();
```

I'm using Vaadin 24.

Answer (score 2):

I think you’re missing explicit heights on the layout components. Try `setHeightFull()` on `layout`, `tableBox`, and `detailsBox`.

Comment: Also: what is that HorizontalLayout placed inside? Whatever that is, it also needs to have a defined height. (Unless it's the root element of the view, in which case it already has height through setSizeFull)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. All Vaadin layout controls are basically flex containers. And this task isn't solvable with flex alone, but it can be solved with custom CSS, which I did following this snippet.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550839/8817161